# How to execute a query daily in a specific time (no SSIS no JOBS)

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I'm doing a generic extractor of information in vb.net to exec any SQL Server query, save data to a txt, compress and send it via FTP (similar to a SSIS package). I have a schedule information too, for example: I want to exec all the queries I configure at 8am and 3pm everyday.

so, I want to know what API should I use to achieve that, using the schedule information I configure? I want to replicate what sql server does with JOBS. I hope you can give some suggestions, thanks in advance

Comment: This question has nothing to do with VB.NET or C#.

Comment: If you have Azure account, You can try to use Azure data factory using which you can perform all the tasks that you mentioned in the question..it is very easy to integrate..

Answer (score 0):

you can attach exe with windows scheduler. It will run your exe on time.

Comment: My problem is that I will have queries which execute on different time, for exampe: query A, B and C everyday at 3am; query D, E day 5 of each month, query x, y each 5 hours and so on

Answer (score -1):

```
class TaskHelper {

    //using System;
    //using System.Diagnostics;
    //using System.IO;
    //using System.Security.Principal;

    public static void CreateSchTasks() {
        string output;
        
        // links to documentation
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks
        // and this one to convert to vb.net
        // https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/ 

        output = SchTaskCmd($"/create /tn _my3amSQL /tr \"c:\\MyApps\\sql_ABC.exe\" /sc daily /st 03:00");
        Console.WriteLine($"{output}");

        output = SchTaskCmd($"/create /tn _my5thDaySQL /tr \"c:\\MyApps\\sql_DE.exe\" /sc monthly /d 5");
        Console.WriteLine($"{output}");

        output = SchTaskCmd($"/create /tn _my5thHourSQL /tr \"c:\\MyApps\\sql_xy.exe\" /sc hourly /mo 5");
        Console.WriteLine($"{output}");
    }

    private static string SchTaskCmd(string cmdLine) {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = $"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)}\\schtasks.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdLine;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.Start();
        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Dispose();
        return output.Trim();
    }
}
```